# Determine mysql submitted values from default values

Tags: mysql, default, fieldtype

I have a mysql table that has an integer column. If no value was submitted, the database defaulted to 0 (zero). Unfortunately this conflicts with what we need as no value should have been stored as null or empty.

The data now has legitimate zeros (submitted) and also default zeros created by the database when no value was entered for the field.

**Just wondering is there any way of determining the submitted zeros from the default zeros?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what data you store in that column, it seems like you need a value MySQL can use to default on, but cannot be chosen by the user.

Overall, as far as I know, there is no way to differentiate whether the value is there due to MySQL's defaults, an insertion, or an update.